# Discord.py Deleted Messages not recovering photos

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In my discord bot, I have a function that collects deleted messages and funnels them to a channel on a separate server. This works perfectly for text but, refuses to work for images. Does anyone have any tips on how I could get this to work for images?

Here is what I have in my event:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, message):
    #print(f"{message.author} deleted a message in #{message.channel}: {message.content}") #Tells the Console about the deleted message
    if message.author == self.client.user:
        return
    elif message.author.bot == True:
        return
    now = datetime.now() #Grabs the current time
    current_time=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") #Formats the current time into a readable form.
    current_date=now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") #Formats the current date into a readable form.
    delete_embed=discord.Embed(title = f"Message Deleted", description= f'**User:** <@{message.author.id}>\n**Channel:** <#{message.channel.id}>\n**Server:** {message.guild}\n**Message:** \n{message.content}', color=0xbf0404)
    delete_embed.set_footer(text=f"Message ID: {message.id}\nDate: {current_date} • Time: {current_time}")
    delete_embed.set_author(name =f"{message.author}", icon_url=f"{message.author.avatar_url}") 
    archive_delete=self.client.get_channel(789080972309168139) #Grabs the ID of the Deleted Messages Channel where the archive is to be stored.
    try:
        delete_embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    await archive_delete.send(embed=delete_embed)
    files=open("DeletedMessages.txt", "a") #Open the text file containing a backup of the deleted messages.
    files.write(f"{message.author}'s message in #{message.channel} in {message.guild} was deleted at {current_time}: '{message.content}'\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.proxy_url` as opposed to `.url`:

```
delete_embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].proxy_url)
```

---

### References:

- [`Attachment.proxy_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.proxy_url) - "When the message is deleted, this URL might be valid for a few minutes or not valid at all."

Comment: This is the only real possibility, otherwise you would need to archive the images of messages yourself.